# Существуют ли публичные сервера MQ очередей

Tags: websphere

Существуют ли публичные сервера MQ очередей, на которых можно проверить работоспособность кода? В гугле не забанили, все что нашел - ссылки на дистрибутивы для установки. Для меня не вариант, свободных компов - нет, виртуалку нетбук не тянет.

Comment: купить raspberry pi? В любом случае, можно на амазоне взять микроинстанс (который в определенных параметрах вроде как бесплатный) и тестить там себе.